# Devise Error Messages Redirect To Unwanted Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have moved my login and signup forms into my home page (the root.) they do their job, user can sign in and sign up successfully. However, when an error is rendered say in a case of signing up and passwords mismatch, user is redirected to the route: /user/sign_up to show that error.
How can I show the errors in the same page (home page) without having the user redirected to the sign up page?
I've already followed the steps [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Integrate-I18n-Flash-Messages-with-Devise-and-Bootstrap).

This is my home.html.erb file:

```
    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

    <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

    <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
    <% end %>
```

And this is my routes:

```
    devise_for :user
    root 'pages#home'
```

PS. I have already tried to change the routes of the sign up to the home route, but errors would still take the user to /user/sign_up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I fixed this by following these tutorials:

For Sign Up

```
http://natashatherobot.com/devise-sign-up-ajax-rails/
```

For Sign In

```
http://natashatherobot.com/devise-rails-sign-in/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the :flash and :notice on application.html.erb like so:

```
    <p class="notice alert alert-info text-center"><%= notice%></p>
      <% elsif alert%>
    <p class="alert alert alert-warning text-center"><%= alert %></p>
```

Devise uses flash messages with I18n with the flash keys :notice and :alert. To customize your app, you can set up your locale file:

You can then customize the alerts and messages:

```
en:
  devise:
    sessions:
      user:
        signed_in: 'Welcome user, you are signed in.'
      admin:
        signed_in: 'Hello admin!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form via ajax in two steps

### Submit login/register forms over ajax

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), remote: true) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

### Override sessions controller to respond to non-html formats

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

```
 def create
   build_resource(sign_up_params)

   if resource.save
   respond_to do |format|
   format.html {
    ...
   }
   format.js {
    ...
   }
   end
  end
 end
```

this is not actually but should give you an idea

Comment: Could you kindly explain your controller further? I'm a total beginner in RoR. Thank you. BTW, I've already tried the controller you posted and without any results. I'm using Rails 4 and Devise 3 @CuriousMind